# View not updating when tap function changes variable used in ngIf condition

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am attempting to show a different portion of my template depending on which button a user taps on.

I'm not sure if this is a case where I need to inform Angular that Change Detection should run? (I'm new to Angular 2, so trying to grasp this concept)

Template:

```
    <Button (tap)="showTab(0)" text="Show Tab 0"></Button>
    <Button (tap)="showTab(1)" text="Show Tab 1"></Button>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="currentTab == 0">
        <Label text="Tab 0"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="currentTab == 1">
        <Label text="Tab 1" class="user-name"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

Component:

```
export class MyComponent {
  currentTab: number = 0;
  ...
  showTab = (num: number) => {
    this.currentTab = num;
  }
  ...
}
```

Behavior:

- The correct Tab (0) shows on initial load, and will disappear when I click on "Show Tab 1", but Tab 1 will not show.
- Clicking back on "Show Tab 0" doesn't do anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you checked value of currentTab  by applying console.log(this.currentTab); in you showTab ?? are you getting any error ?

Comment: Amit- yes, I am able to console log the value of this.currentTab and it is set correctly. No errors in the console.

Comment: I tested your code and did not have any issues on iOS emulator. I would check which versions you are using as they might be out of date. Also which platform did you use and was this on a real device or an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me. but can you try making your currentTab: boolean=false;

and code as

```
    <Button (tap)="showTab(false)" text="Show Tab 0"></Button>
    <Button (tap)="showTab(true)" text="Show Tab 1"></Button>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="!currentTab">
        <Label text="Tab 0"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="currentTab">
        <Label text="Tab 1" class="user-name"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

and

```
export class MyComponent {
  currentTab: boolean = false;
  ...
  showTab(num: boolean){
    this.currentTab = num;
  }
  ...
}
```

also try this way showTab(num: number){ } in place of showTab = (num: number) => {} ; and check your types.

Comment: I have tried this, with the same result. I can see the boolean value properly in the console, but the view is not updated. Could it be something with using ngIf on NativeScript layout tags?

Comment: this normaly work in angular. i daily use these kind of things. i have not tried NativeScript yet. but if its related to change detection then you should try ngZone. Sometimes when i use integration of meteor and angular 2 i face these kind of issue. try ngZone. check my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145290/alert-in-meteor-angular-2-app-only-appears-after-click-in-browser  hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using **[hidden]** instead of ***ngIf** ?